# I need to move from One Series to Two Series

Tags: c#, .net, charts, logic

We are using the dotNETCHARTING to portray our charts, they accepts `Series` for their `SeriesCollection`. This is a new chart I'm working on, all the previous ones have a 1:1 relation between value shown and value extracted. Now I have a list of values to show as a list of values 12:12.

I currently have my 2 lists of data showing (Actual vs Budgetted over the past 12 months) - but in a single `Series`, where they should be 2 `Series`. I have the data sorted and listed as needed, well almost listed right.

Restrictions: .NET 3.5 (VS2008), dotNETCHARTING.

It will be a very sad solution if I had to create 12 SQLs for each month and 12 for the budgetted. From what I see that is not necessary, as soon as I find a way to seperate each list into seperate `Series`.

Each Module has a `List<ModuleValue>`, I have tried with a `Dictionary<int, List<ModuleValue>>` so that each series of values (12months) could have a seperate List.

I have tried the For each list of Values, add each value in the list to a `Series`, repeat until out of List of values. (`Foreach` in a `Foreach`)

My question is: Can anyone give me some pointers to a possible solution. Graph below is per say correct, if there weren't lined up one after the other, but started and ended at the same timeframe (month). Eg budget for Jan compares to actual for Jan. I'm not asking about the dotNETCHARTING module, they have plenty of help. I'm asking for this mid-between and how it feeds the data to the module.

Main logic body:

```
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            base.CreateChildControls();

            //_chart.Type = ChartType.Combo;
            _chart.DefaultSeries.Type = SeriesType.Line;

// Up for change - between here
            IList listSeries = new List();
            listSeries.Add(GetSeries(_module)); // This line should be listSeries = GetMultipleSeries(_module); or to that effect.

            foreach (var series in listSeries)
            {
                _chart.SeriesCollection.Add(series);
            }
// Up for change - and here

            // This shows the title above the chart:
            _chart.Title = _module.Title;
            // This shows the title below the chart:
            //_chart.XAxis.Label = new Label(_module.Title);

            _chart.TitleBox.Line.Color = Charter.BackgroundColor;

            base.SetAreaStyles();
            base.SetLinkUrl(_module.LinkUrl);
        }
```

This logic is the old logic, should remain as is - because all the other charts rely on it.
Can be used as a point of reference. Consider this logic locked.

```
        protected Series GetSeries(FrontModule module)
        {
            Series series = new Series(module.Title);

            foreach (var value in module.Values)
            {
                string sFieldTitle = value.Text;

                Element element = new Element(sFieldTitle, value.Value);

                element.Color = Charter.GetColor(value.ColorIndex);

                series.Elements.Add(element);

                string sToolTip = string.Format
                    ("{0}: {1:N0}"
                    , value.Tooltip
                    , value.Value);

                element.ToolTip = sToolTip;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.LinkUrl))
                {
                    element.URL = Page.ResolveUrl(value.LinkUrl);
                }

                ChartTooltip += string.Concat(sToolTip, ", ");
            }

            ChartTooltip += "\n";

            return series;
        }
```

This is the new Logic and should be changed to reflect the desired logic. Consider this as free as can be.

```
        protected List GetMultipleSeries(FrontModule module)
        {
            List listSeries = new List();
            Series series = new Series(module.Title);

            foreach (var keyPair in module.DictionaryValues)
            {
                string sFieldTitle = keyPair.Value.Text;

                Element element = new Element(sFieldTitle, keyPair.Value.Value);

                element.Color = Charter.GetColor(keyPair.Value.ColorIndex);

                series.Elements.Add(element);

                string sToolTip = string.Format
                    ("{0}: {1:N0}"
                    , keyPair.Value.Tooltip
                    , keyPair.Value.Value);

                element.ToolTip = sToolTip;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyPair.Value.LinkUrl))
                {
                    element.URL = Page.ResolveUrl(keyPair.Value.LinkUrl);
                }

                ChartTooltip += string.Concat(sToolTip, ", ");

            }

            listSeries.Add(series);

            ChartTooltip += "\n";

            return listSeries;
        }
```

[image]

This is how it shouldn't be, listing data in a sequal line. Though it shows it has all the required data.

I'd appreciate anything you could add. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two `Series` objects:

```
    protected List GetMultipleSeries(FrontModule module)
    {
        List listSeries = new List();
        Series seriesActual = new Series(module.Title);
        Series seriesBudgetted = new Series(module.Title);

        foreach (var keyPair in module.DictionaryValues)
        {
            string sFieldTitle = keyPair.Value.Text;

            Element element = new Element(sFieldTitle, keyPair.Value.Value);

            element.Color = Charter.GetColor(keyPair.Value.ColorIndex);

            // Is is actual or budgetted
            if (keyPair.Value.IsActual)
                seriesActual.Elements.Add(element);
            else
                seriesBudgetted.Elements.Add(element);

            string sToolTip = string.Format
                ("{0}: {1:N0}"
                , keyPair.Value.Tooltip
                , keyPair.Value.Value);

            element.ToolTip = sToolTip;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyPair.Value.LinkUrl))
            {
                element.URL = Page.ResolveUrl(keyPair.Value.LinkUrl);
            }

            ChartTooltip += string.Concat(sToolTip, ", ");

        }

        listSeries.Add(seriesActual);
        listSeries.Add(seriesBudgetted);

        ChartTooltip += "\n";

        return listSeries;
    }
```

I'm assuming you have some way of testing whether the points are actual or budgetted for the if statement.

Comment: Ohh u'r saying something there. Let me test that. Cheers.